# C言語の文字列のソートについて

Tags: c

C言語で、ASCを入力したら昇順
DESCを入力したら降順のプログラムを作ろうとしているのですが、降順の方が上手くいかず、どなたか間違っている個所を教えて頂けないでしょうか？

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(char* a, char* b) {
    char t[10];
    strcpy(t, a);
    strcpy(a, b);
    strcpy(b, t);
}

void sort(char s[][6], int n, int f) {
    int i, j, t;
    if (f == 0) {
        for (i = 1;i < n;i++) {
            for (j = 1;j < n;j++) {
                if (strcmp(s[j - 1], s[j]) > 0) {
                    strcpy(t, s[j - 1]);
                    strcpy(s[j - 1], s[j]);
                    strcpy(s[j], t);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
            for (i = 1;i < n;i++) {
                for (j = 1;j < n;j++) {
                    if (strcmp(s[j - 1], s[j]) < 0) {
                        strcpy(t, s[j - 1]);
                        strcpy(s[j - 1], s[j]);
                        strcpy(s[j], t);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

void main()
{
    int i, n;
    char sin[9][6];
    char com[16];
    FILE* fp;

    fp = fopen("before_sort2.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("ファイルオープン失敗\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%s", &(sin[i]));
    }
    fclose(fp);

    printf("command >");
    scanf("%s", com);
    if (strcmp(com, "ASC") == 0) {
        sort(sin, 9, 0);
    }
    else if (strcmp(com, "DESC") == 0) {
        sort(sin, 9, 1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", sin[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VC++でビルドすると以下のようなエラーと警告が報告されます。(フォーマットは変えています)
降順処理が出来るか否かよりも、最初の昇順処理も完全では無かったということでしょう。

```
行  種類    内容
17  エラー  初期化されていないローカル変数 't' が使用されます
17  警告    '関数': 間接参照のレベルが 'char *' と 'int' で異なっています。
17  警告    'strcpy': の型が 1 の仮引数および実引数と異なります。
19  警告    '関数': 間接参照のレベルが 'char *' と 'int' で異なっています。
19  警告    'strcpy': の型が 2 の仮引数および実引数と異なります。
       28行目と30行目もそれぞれ17行目と19行目と同じ警告(エラーは表示されないが内容は同じ)
39  警告    'n': ローカル変数は 1 度も使われていません。
48  警告    'main': 戻り値の型が 'void' で宣言された関数が、値を返しました。
```

Comment: gccは大量の警告は出力されますがビルドは出来ました。完全で無いというか、strcpyのdistにintを指定しているので落ちなければ奇跡ですね。

Answer (score 0):

sort関数のオート変数tが間違っています。
qsort標準関数を使わないのは学校の課題だからですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうざいます。qsortを使わない方法でやる事になりました。初歩的な質問ですいません、tをどう変えたら良いでしょうか？